# Do these sentences have the same meaning: "I thought so." vs "That is what I thought."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

You are applying for a loan and you talk about it at the bank. The loan managers says:

**"You need at least 10% of the total value, plus enough to cover other rates and expenses."**

(Before you have come to the bank, you made some calculations at home, and figured out nearly the same numbers, similar rates, etc.)

So do you say, in reply to the loan manager:

**OK,That is what I thought.**

OR do you say:

**I thought so.**

These two sentences seem to have the same meaning. Do they really have the same meaning?

Comment: "I thought so" sounds more casual or dismissive. You could say either in this context, but they wouldn't necessarily convey the same attitude. It depends what you mean by "interchangeable".

Comment: @StuartF I find they're both dismissive with the right tone. "*That's what I thought **too***" or "*I thought so **too***" make it clearly inoffensive.

Comment: Are you asking whether those two sentences are (1) *exactly the same in every possible context*, or (2) *interchangeable in that function of saying you had the same thought*, or (3) *interchangeable in that one specific context at the bank*?

Comment: I am asking number 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sentences are not identical in all contexts.

For one example, "That's what I thought" can mean, "I've had that thought/opinion", whereas "I thought so" cannot have this meaning.

But in contexts where the meaning is "that confirms what I believe", the two are interchangeable in all contexts I can think of. I can't confidently say there are no contexts at all where they're different.